# how can I clear or set values in a digestive-functors view

Tags: haskell, reform, digestive-functors

I have used `postForm` from `Text.Digestive` in `digestive-functions` which returns something like a `(Just view, Nothing)` in the case of a form error. I can then take the view and render it to HTML to display the form errors.

My issue is that I do not want *every* field to be rendered as given by the user. Specifically, my captcha value should be reset to a newly computed one rather than reusing the old one (which would give an infinite number of captcha attempts). But I do not know how to compute a new view with one field cleared/set, given the old view.

Alternatively, does anyone know if this would be easier with reform? I haven't looked at it much yet but it seems nice that it does away with the string-based-programming part of digestive-functors.

Comment: Stop using CAPTCHA. It's terrible for accessibility. That will solve your problem.

Comment: You are right, but can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repeated the question on the bug tracker where someone eventually came up with a [working hack](https://github.com/jaspervdj/digestive-functors/issues/121). The view value turns out the be a record. You can mutate its viewInput field before rendering it. viewInput is an association list from paths to forms.